# Why is IsEmpty(Target) not working on my Worksheet_Change() sub in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am newer to working with VBA and cannot understand why IsEmpty(Target) isn't working in my subroutine.
I have a worksheet in which users fill in values to column "A" from a drop down list.   Depending on the value they choose different things should happen on columns "B" and "C".

1)If they chose "Active" from the drop down list then column "B" and "C" get unlocked and they are able to choose values from another drop down list for each column.
2)If they change the value from "Active" to anything else, then columns "B" and "C" should lock again and their respective values should be deleted.
3)If they erase the value of column "A" the value of the respective row for column "B" and "C" should also be deleted and cells should lock. This is where I'm running into issues.

Step 1 and 2 are working fine, but when I erase the value of column "A" nothing happens to columns "B" and "C".  I have been doing a lot of research and can't figure out what is wrong with my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        
        If Target = "Active" Then
            Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":" & "C" & ActiveCell.Row).Locked = False
        ElseIf Target <> "Active" Then
            Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":" & "C" & ActiveCell.Row).ClearContents
            Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":" & "C" & ActiveCell.Row).Locked = True
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Target) Then
            Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":" & "C" & ActiveCell.Row).ClearContents
            Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":" & "C" & ActiveCell.Row).Locked = True
        End If
        ActiveS
```

I also tried changing IsEmpty(Target) to Target = "" and no change, nothing happens when values in column "A" are deleted.

Comment: Seems like there are only two cases "Active" or "not active" (which also includes "")

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tim, I tried only having two cases  "Active" and "<>Active", works great except when there is no value at all.  That's why I added the third case, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Suggest you use an intermediate variable to see what Target actually contains. eg Dim v as Variant: v= Target.Value. Then set a breakpoint and look at "v" in the Locals window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, notActive As Boolean
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Me.Unprotect
    For Each c In rng.Cells                'in case >1 cell is changed
        notActive = c.Value <> "Active"
        With c.EntireRow.Range("B1:C1")    'range is relative to the row
            .Locked = notActive
            If notActive Then .ClearContents
        End With
    Next c
    Me.Protect
    
End Sub
```